# Disabling the viewstate both on page and control does not have effect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have disabled the viewstate for controls (labels, buttons etc) and the page for test purposes.

Now when I change the text of a label on the client side and intercept the button's click event, the label still shows the text that the server sent previously.

So what is going on? I need to be able to change data on the client and have it available to the server.

How is this done?

Comment: It sounds like you are not posting back to the server, or you are posting back to the server but not changing anything there. How does the server handle the post back? Disabling the view state won't matter much here the text is what the server sent because it is the text for that control and it does not seem as though you have changed it on the server, just the client.

Comment: I handle the postback in Click event of the button where I set the breakpoint. Yes Just want to change it on the client and by disbaling the viewstate I want to disable the server involvement with the data persistence. When i disable the viewstate then I should not matter whether I change the data on server or client. It that it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You want to not persist the changed text, but you do want the changed text to be available to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Labels are rendered as `spans` on the client side; as such, you won't be able to capture the changes on the server side since they are not input elements.

ASP.NET gives you the illusion of being able to change the label's text programmatically, simply because it uses the ViewState to store/retrieve this information on every postback. By disabling it, you are giving up on using this "feature".

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a [hidden input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx).

On your form add:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hiddenHolder" />
```

Then in the client on click event when you change the text of the label, also change the `value` of the `hiddenHolder`.

In your code behind you can then get the value with:

```
string LabelText = hiddenHolder.Value;
```

In this way the change you made on the client is available to the server